# How can I pipe stderr and still test if the command failed?

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr, error-checking

I would like to write a one-liner for cron that will:

1. Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to logger
2. Test if the command fails
3. Perform an action if that happens

I have a script that will print some things and then exit badly.

**script.sh:**

```
SCRIPT=`basename "$0"`
echo $SCRIPT is running...
\>&2 echo $SCRIPT has failed!
exit 1
```

When I run the script without piping to logger, everything is fine.  When I pipe everything to logger for review at a later date, the error check fails.  Is there a way to have both the pipe and the error check work at the same time?

```
\>script.sh
script.sh is running...
script.sh failed!

\>script.sh || echo foo
script.sh is running...
script.sh failed!
foo

\>script.sh 2>&1 | logger || echo foo
\>
```

Comment: Check that `logger` is on your PATH in `cron`, or use its full path.

Comment: The pipe to logger is working fine.  The problem is that once I have piped to logger, the error condition no longer trips the second half of the command (echo foo).

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
set -o pipefail
script.sh |& logger || echo foo
```

Another way:

```
(script.sh |& logger; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}) || echo foo
```

See [`man bash`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> `PIPESTATUS` An array variable containing a list of exit             status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed
>                 foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: >>(script.sh |& logger; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}) || echo foo

Works like a charm.  What wizardry is this?  Can you explain to me why this works?

Comment: @coldspringhead Added `PIPESTATUS` note for you. `|&` is redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` into the pipe. `()` starts a sub-shell.